# pdflib - sh: phpize: command not found

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I need my website to generate a pdf file.  I was planning on using PDFlib.  When I try install it through the PEAR graphic interface, I get the error message "sh: phpize: command not found".  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Most likely you need the PHP development libraries. On Debian-derived systems, it'd be something like `apt-get install php5-dev`.

Comment: OK, so maybe I am really going to showcase my ignorance, but I don't know where to go to access a command line.

Comment: I can't get onto an Ubuntu console right now, but going off vague memories, it's under System -> Terminal or something like that. Even if you can't get to a shell, there's always GUI package managers like Synaptic from which you can do the install.

Answer (score 16):

As noted by Marc B, you should have in your system a package containing the files needed for building PHP extensions (php-devel, usually).

On my Centos system you should type this command as root in a terminal:

```
yum install php-devel
```

This should work on Red Hat and Fedora, by the way.

On Debian or Ubuntu the command is slightly different:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

If you want to start a terminal, the steps required depend on your desktop environment. Usually on Ubuntu users get Unity installed, so:

```
 Dash -> More Apps -> Accessories -> Terminal
```

On Gnome3:

```
 Applications menu -> Accessories -> Terminal
```

The keyboard shortcut is the same on both environment: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>T</kbd> .

For other DEs take a look at this doc: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal